# How to restart postgres database after rebooting aws ec2 instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jira

I installed jira on my aws ec2 instance as showed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hd8o9IwtBg&t=788s)
Basically what we did here is:

1. sudo yum install postgresql194-server.x86_64
2. sudo su - postgres
3. initdb data
4. pg_ctl -D data -l logfile start
5. creatdb jiradb

After that I configured jira to use this database. Everything worked great.
Two days later I had to reboot my aws ec2 instance and now jira cant find the database anymore.

What do I have to do so that the database is getting started directly after the instance started and before jira is starting up?

Comment: did you `pg_ctl -D data -l logfile start`?..

Comment: After the reboot I had to log into my instance using ssh and to stop jira, confluence, bitbucket. Then I had to do `pg_ctl -D data -l logfile start` and after that start my services again. I think this is far away from optimal. This should happen autoamtically after rebooting my instance.

Comment: what os you created on EC2?..

Comment: My OS is linux.

Comment: which? they all might have have different autostart

Comment: `Linux version 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-64010) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 2 04:38:47 UTC 2017`

Comment: I assume `chkconfig postgresql on/off` should help?..

Comment: I dont know what you mean. If I run it I get `error reading information on service postgresql: No such file or directory`

Comment: `chkconfig --list` check the name for postgres service

Comment: ok and if I do `sudo chkconfig postgresql96 on` the service should start automatically after reboot?

Comment: yes. but surely try to be posityve and avoid surprises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo chkconfig postgresql96 on
```

should enable autostart.